Filling in missing steps in a proof of the revenue equivalence theorem
I'm working through these slides from Asu Ozdaglar, which give an exposition of the revenue equivalence theorem that is slightly more general than the examples I have studied before. However, the result she presents seems vacuous to me, and I am trying to obtain a deeper intuition.
In her notation, $x_i \geq 0$ is buyer $i$'s private valuation, and a (direct) mechanism $(Q, M)$ maps stated valuations (bids) to probabilities of winning the object $Q_i(x)$ and payments $M_i(x)$ made by the buyers to the auctioneer.
Thus each player wants to maximize $Q_i(x) x_i - M_i (x)$.
Ozdaglar also defines the helper functions $q_i(z_i)$ and $m_i(z_i)$, which give the values of $Q_i(x)$ and $M_i(x)$ at $x_i = z_i$ in expectation over the other players' valuations ($x_{-i}$), and
$$
U_i(x_i) = \max_{z_i} \{q_i(z_i) x_i - m_i(z_i)\}
$$
which is player $i$'s expected payoff when bidding optimally (i.e. in equilibrium).
On slides 11 and 12, Ozdaglar uses the second fundamental theorem of calculus to show that if the mechanism is incentive compatible, then
$$
U_i(x_i) = U_i(0) + \int_{0}^{x_i} q_i(t_i) dt_t
$$
and writes:

This shows that, up to an additive constant, the expected payoff to a buyer in an IC direct mechanism $(Q, M)$ depends only on the allocation rule $Q$.

I feel like the "up to an additive constant" bit renders this observation vacuous. The additive constant $U_i(0)$ is equal to $\max_{z_i} \{ - m_i(z_i)\}$ and thus plainly depends on $M$ (not just via $m_i(0)$, but the entire curve of $m_i(z_i)$). Thus, to me the above sentence reads as

This shows that, up to an additive constant that depends on $M$, the expected payoff to a buyer in an IC direct mechanism $(Q, M)$ depends only on the allocation rule $Q$.

which amounts to "the expected payoff depends on $M$ and $Q$," which is the entire mechanism.
What am I missing here?
I think that unpacking my misunderstanding above might help me make sense of Ozdaglar's statement of the revenue equivalence theorem on page 13, which is that

If the direct mechanism is incentive compatible, then for all $x_i$, the expected payment is $$m_i(x_i) = m_i(0) + q_i(x_i) x_i - \int_{0}^{x_i} q_i(t_i) dt_i.$$

I don't see how this follows from the above. Where does $m_i(0)$ come from?

In an incentive-compatible mechanism,
$$\max_{z_i} \{q_i(z_i) x_i - m_i(z_i)\}=q_i(x_i)x_i-m_i(x_i).$$
So once we know the mechanism is incentive compatible, we can forget about the global behavior.
Now, we have $U_i(x_i)=q_i(x_i)x_i-m_i(x_i)$ and $U_i(0)=q_i(0)0-m_i(0)=-m_i(0),$ so
$$U_i(x_i) = U_i(0) + \int_{0}^{x_i} q_i(t_i) dt_i$$
translates to
$$q_i(x_i)x_i-m_i(x_i) = -m_i(0) + \int_{0}^{x_i} q_i(t_i) dt_i,$$
from which
$$m_i(x_i) = m_i(0) + q_i(x_i)x_i - \int_{0}^{x_i} q_i(t_i) dt_i$$
follows.

Thank you, that makes sense. Do you have any light to shed on the main question about why the result isn't vacuous?

Well, the formula depends only on $q_i$ and $m_i(0)$, so definitely not on all of $M$.

When I hear "revenue equivalence," I think: "Once you (the auctioneer) pick your allocation $Q$, you can choose any $M$ you want, but as long as the pair is incentive compatible, your revenue will be the same." But if we sum that $m_i(x_i)$ expression to get the auctioneer's revenue, we get a term that includes $\sum_i m_i(0)$, which the auctioneer could vary considerably by picking $M$. I think the theorem is saying, "Sure, but if IC holds, the optimal $x_i$ will cancel the profits out," but I don't see how that follows from the $m_i(x_i) = \dots$ expression. It feels like a new claim.

The point is exactly that you don't have much choice if you want the mechanism to be incentive compatible. Once you settled on the allocation rule, you can only change the entry fee.

So why not pick $M$ with $m_i(0) = 1000000$ to guarantee a high profit no matter how players bid?

@Max One usually includes an individual rationality or participation constraint that rules that out.

Yeah, that's kind of why I'm confused. If you add an assumption like "also, individual rationality holds and Q must award the item to the highest bidder," then the result becomes interesting, because now the theorem really says something about how much profit the auctioneer can make. But in the slides I linked, that discussion appears after the presentation of the theorem. I'm trying to make sense of this more general version of the theorem and whether it is useful other than the fact that it incorporates more familiar results as a special case.

What the result is useful for is different from.the question whether it is trivial.

The statement "all four-sided polygons are polygons" includes "all squares are polygons" as a special case, but the latter statement is much narrower than the former and could be proven directly using the definition of a polygon. And it would be a stretch to call the former the "generalized all-squares-are-polygons theorem" given that it includes shapes that are not squares.

Similarly, I know how to prove (directly) a revenue equivalence theorem for auctions with individual rationality and in which the item has to go to the highest bidder, but this is a much narrower result (in particular, $Q$ is deterministic). Why should I care about this more general result if its notion of "revenue" is so abstract that you have to add additional assumptions and take a special case to make sense of it?

What the theorem is useful for is a different question.

OK, then suppose that is the question I am asking.
